# How to delete entry in Java TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap

I am making a method, which takes a provided TreeMap, removes entries where the key is a multiple of keyFilter **and** the value contains the valueFilter character, and then returns the resulting TreeMap.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, String> filterTreeMap(
        TreeMap<Integer, String> map, int keyFilter, char valueFilter) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int mapKey = entry.getKey();
        String mapValue = entry.getValue();
        if (mapKey%keyFilter == 0 && mapValue.indexOf(valueFilter) != -1) {
            map.remove(mapKey);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

However, under the if condition where I want to delete the entries, I don't know how to delete entries in tree map. As far as I know, there is no existing method that I can use?

Comment: You should not implicitly iterate over a map and use `remove` at the same time as that can result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Use an explicit iterator on the entry set and call the `remove` method of that iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `Iterator`. As the [`Iterator.remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) Javadoc notes

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Something like

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, String> filterTreeMap(TreeMap<Integer, String> map,
        int keyFilter, char valueFilter) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = iter.next();
        int mapKey = entry.getKey();
        String mapValue = entry.getValue();
        if (mapKey % keyFilter == 0 && mapValue.indexOf(valueFilter) != -1) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to apply method [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to the entry set.

> `default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`
> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate. Errors or runtime exceptions thrown during iteration or by the predicate are relayed to the caller.
>
> *Implementation Requirements:*
> The default implementation traverses all elements of the collection using its `iterator()`. Each matching element is removed using `Iterator.remove()`. If the collection's iterator does not support removal then an `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown on the first matching element.

Then the method `filterTreeMap` may have `void` return type because the input `map` is modified and this change will be "visible" outside this method.

```java
public static void filterTreeMap(
        TreeMap<Integer, String> map, int keyFilter, char valueFilter) {
    map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> 
        e.getKey() % keyFilter == 0
        && e.getValue().indexOf(valueFilter) != -1
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keys on the map are unique. So, find that keys, and then remove them form the map.

```
public static TreeMap<Integer, String> filterTreeMap(TreeMap<Integer, String> map,
                int keyFilter, char valueFilter) {
                
                Set<Integer> keysToRemove = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(kv -> kv.getKey() % keyFilter == 0 && kv.getValue().indexOf(valueFilter) != -1) // can be Predicate parameter
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
                keysToRemove.forEach(map::remove);
                
                return map; // keep in mind, map is modified here. You might want to return a new map instead
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a copy and you can add/remove just fine:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> (map).entrySet()) {
    int mapKey = entry.getKey();
    String mapValue = entry.getValue();
    if (mapKey%keyFilter == 0 && mapValue.indexOf(valueFilter) != -1) {
        map.remove(mapKey);
    }
}
```

It's not even any more lines of code, because the copy is made in-line via the copy constructor. `LinkedHashMap` was chosen to preserve iteration order (if that matters).